# Condition Statement in Mutate R not working correctly

Tags: r

When I run the following code on my dataset as follows:

```
Master_calc <- w %>% mutate(f_100_nom = case_when(round(f_100,2) <= F_100_weights ~ 1, TRUE~  0 ))
```

on the following Data:

| id | f_100 | F100_weights |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | -0.07 |
| 2 | 0.8591463 | -0.07 |
| 3 | 0 | -0.07 |
| 4 | 0 | -0.07 |

I get:

| id | f_100 | F100_weights | f_100_nom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | -0.07 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.8591463 | -0.07 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | -0.07 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | -0.07 | 0 |

Result should be:

| id | f_100 | F100_weights | f_100_nom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | -0.07 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.8591463 | -0.07 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | -0.07 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | -0.07 | 1 |

The condition I want is: when f_100 <= F100_weights then 1 else 0.
I cannot for the life of me figure out what is happening here, or am i writing the conditions wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: We can't test this without a dataset to work with. Please provide a [mcve] of your dataset that reproduces the problem. Ideally, make it as short as possible and use `dput` to output it as text which you can paste into the question

Comment: **Why would you expect anything else?**  Let `x_100 <- c(0, 0.86)` and `X100_weight <- c(-0.05, -0.05)`. Then for `round(x_100, 2)` we get `c(0.00 0.86)`, so for `round(x_100, 2) <= X100_weight` we get `c(FALSE, FALSE)`; as each value in `x_100` is in fact *greater than* the negative number `-0.05`. Since each case evaluates to `FALSE` and therefore defaults to `0`, then for `case_when(round(x_100, 2) <= X100_weight ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)` we get `c(0, 0)`.

Comment: F100_weights is `-0.07`, so it's lower than all the values of `f_100`. This is the correct answer. If you expect different, maybe you wanted to compare with the absolute value of F100_weights, which would give you the right answer?

Comment: Thanks guys i was so out of it yesterday....long work day, my brain was basically fried.